# PHP код в правом сайдбаре WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как вставить PHP код в правый сайдбар WordPress?

Как он называется? Какая страничка отвечает за вывод информации для правого сайдбара?

Comment: Как называется кто? код?

Comment: Как называется страничка с php кодом? Где я могу вставить свой код, который затем отобразится в провом сайдбаре

Comment: "Страничкой" вы называете темплейт? Ничего не понял!

Comment: Внешний вид -> Редактор -> Шаблоны (с правой стороны). Вот как раз их я имею ввиду. Какой из них отвечает за отображение информации в правом сайдбаре мне нужно узнать...

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос задан не верно.

Я бы порекондовал почитать документацию о темах.

А именно в Вашем случае:

1. Вам нужно вставить код в динамический сайдбар, что не возможно.
2. Динамические сайдбары зависят от темы, что используется, и они регистрируються кодом, `functions.php` например:

   `add_action('register_addittional_sidebars','add__dynamic_sidebars');
    do_action('register_addittional_sidebars');`

   ```
   function add__dynamic_sidebars(){
   $params = [
             'id'            => 'my-bar',
             'name'          => __('Мой сайдбар'),
             'description'   => __('Описание сдесь'),
             'class'         => '',
             'before_widget' => '',
             'after_widget'  => '',
             'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
             'after_title'   => '</h2>'
             ];
   register_sidebar($params);
   }
   ```

   Далее, у вас в админ панели на странице виджетов появится сайдбар с названием `Мой сайдбар` , к нему можно применить виджеты, а для отображения в темплейте просто нужо сделать его вызов кодом `dynamic_sidebar( 'my-bar' );`.

Если же Вам нужен сайдбар с Вашим кастомным php кодом, то нужно делать по методу:

1. Создать файл в корне темы с именем `sidebar-my.php`.
2. Написать нужный код в созданый сайдбар\файл.
3. В нужном месте темы или её темплейта вызвать наш сайдбар функцией `get_sidebar('my');`, WordPress автоматически подхватит файл из корня темы `sidebar-my.php`.

Во втором методе, Ваш сайдбар не динамический, следовательно не будет отображатся в панели администрирования.

Можно сделать комбо вариант:
 1. Выполнить действия при первом варианте.
 2. Выполнить действия при втором варианте, но непосредственоо вставить динамический сайдбар в наш статичный, тоесть добавить строчку `dynamic_sidebar( 'my-bar' );` внутрь `sidebar-my.php` файла. А далее использывать статический сайдбар в нужном месте.

Повторюсь ещо, все динамические сайдбары зависят от темы, тоесть вам нужно искать в теме строчки с использыванием `register_sidebar()`, но добавить код к сайдбару не сможете, так как файло который отвечает за него попросту не существует.

Answer (score 0):

Я в подобной ситуации делал проще. Но через плагин.
Качаю плагин который называется PHP Code Widget
Пишем в виджете php код и вставляем его в любую зону виджетов.
И все работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]